# My jQuery script will work on my local machine but not my server. Why is this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

really the only thing I can say is that my jQuery won't load on my server. It works fine on my local machine though. I checked and jQuery and my script are both loading fine (as far as I can tell). The site is www.ingramsflooring.com/v2/index.html

The big white area under the header should be an image rotator. If there is anymore info I can give to help solve this please let me know. Tahnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually loading two copies of jQuery 1.7.1:

```
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script><!-- Found in the head -->
```

and

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>>!-- Found at the bottom of the page -->
```

I believe your problem is that you are including jQuery, then the `js/s3slider.js` plugin (which alters jQuery to include itself), but then you re-load jQuery which overrides the plugin...

So I suggest only loading jQuery once, at the bottom of the page along with the plugin (the plugin should load just after the jQuery Core).

What lead me to believe this is the error message output by your page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 's3Slider'
```

Even though you included the plugin it's not recognized by the time you try to use it.

## Update

You *could* use `$.noConflict()` to create a copy of the first jQuery Core before loading the second, but I do not recommend this as you're loading the exact same version twice.

Comment: @user715564 I forgot to answer why it worked locally but not when hosted remotely. When you were looking at the page locally, the remote version of jQuery was not being loaded (many browsers don't allow online resources to load when looking at a page locally). But when you uploaded the page, both jQuery includes were being used.